# First occurence in table based on values of another table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I have the Following tables:

Tab1:

```
Variable timestamp
s1       1053093896
s2       1053095216
s1       1053181616
s1       1053959216
s2       1054132016
```

and Tab2:

```
Variable timestamp
s1       1053129600
s2       1053820800
```

I want to extract the first occurrence for each variable where the timestamps of tab1 is higher than those of tab2. The result I seek is as follows:

```
Variable timestamp
s1       1053181616
s2       1054132016
```

Comment: merge and filter sounds like a solid plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way using the `dplyr` package.
I modified the numbers for better readability.

```
df1 <- data.frame(variable = c("s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s2"),
           timestamp = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(variable = c("s1", "s2"),
                  timestamp = c(2, 4), stringsAsFactors = F)
> df1
  variable timestamp
1       s1         1
2       s2         2
3       s1         3
4       s1         4
5       s2         5

> df2
  variable timestamp
1       s1         2
2       s2         4

 library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "variable", suffix = c("", "_2")) %>% 
  filter(timestamp > timestamp_2) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(-timestamp_2)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   variable [2]
  variable timestamp
  <chr>        <int>
1 s1               3
2 s2               5
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems like I have a problem with incompatibility :
Can't join on 'variable' x 'variable' because of incompatible types (integer / factor).
However, when I check the type using typeof I get the same type which is integer.

Comment: Hi, your Variable column is probably of type factor. Try to convert it to character by using as.character()

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I converted the columns from factor to integer using as.numeric(as.character(variable))

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a left join using the indicated logical expression:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select b.Variable, min(a.timestamp) as timestamp 
  from tab2 b 
  left join tab1 a on a.Variable = b.Variable and a.timestamp > b.timestamp
  group by b.Variable")
```

giving:

```
  Variable  timestamp
1       s1 1053181616
2       s2 1054132016
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "Variable timestamp
s1       1053093896
s2       1053095216
s1       1053181616
s1       1053959216
s2       1054132016"
tab1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "Variable timestamp
s1       1053129600
s2       1053820800"
tab2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A non join/merge solution is to pass `Variable` and `timestamp` in `Map` filter `tab1` based on condition and select the first row and `rbind` the list of rows.

```
do.call(rbind, 
    Map(function(x, y) tab1[with(tab1, which.max(Variable == x & timestamp > y)), ],
                       tab2$Variable, tab2$timestamp))


#  Variable  timestamp
#3       s1 1053181616
#5       s2 1054132016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a data.table join by ordering your data and using the `mult = 'first'` option

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data tables
setDT(tab1)
setDT(tab2)
# order data (unecessary if already ordered)
setorder(tab1, timestamp)
setorder(tab2, timestamp)

tab1[tab2, on = .(Variable, timestamp > timestamp), mult = 'first',
     .(Variable, x.timestamp)]

#    Variable x.timestamp
# 1:       s1  1053181616
# 2:       s2  1054132016
```

Data used

```
tab1 <- fread('
Variable timestamp
s1       1053093896
s2       1053095216
s1       1053181616
s1       1053959216
s2       1054132016
')

tab2 <- fread('
Variable timestamp
s1       1053129600
s2       1053820800
')
```